# Java. How to access methods of a class when it has been placed in a list of generic objects

Tags: java, oop

I have some classes called `Equipment` and `Product` that are children of a class `Item`. I am storing imported equipment and products in `ArrayList<Item>`. I need to access the unique methods of `Equipment` and `Product` iteratively from that list.

I'm aware using `instanceOf` is generally bad practice, but this is a simplified version of what I've tried.

```
for(Item i: listOfItems){
   if(i.itemType instanceOf Equipment){
      i.getEquipmentVin();
   }
}
```

Comment: Unless Equipment and Product share the same set of methods you will have to use code to differentiate them.

Comment: Perhaps you could show a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: sounds like a design problem.  What is the relationship between Product and Equipment?

Comment: As an aside, in commercial programming you hardly ever use inheritance. Things are not usually similar enough to warrant baking inheritance into them, and usually not even via interfaces. The classic example of Vehicle with subclasses Car, Truck, Motorcycle etc doesn't actually occur in real life DMVs (I've worked at two in different countries btw). Stuff is just different from other stuff, and any similarities are not worth the trouble worrying about.

Comment: @Bohemian I cannot follow your claim that inheritance is hardly ever used. Even on my entity classes I have inheritance, allowing me to model generic fields like created/lastmodified time stamps once for all. It may be your practice though.

Comment: @Queeg if you read my comment carefully, you'll see it contains the phrase "in commercial programming". ie it real-life coding jobs, you rarely see inheritance. In academic contexts, such as this question, you see it *over* used (to illustrate a language feature that a professional coder will rarely use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of Items (or some Item), you can only call Item methods on it. But you can cast it to Equipment (or Product) and then call the respective methods. Just be aware that casting an Item to Equipment while at runtime it is a Product (or something else) will give you a ClassCastException.

To work around that, first identify what you have before you cast:

```
if (item instanceof Equipment) {
    Equipment e = (Equipment)item;
    e.getEquipmentVin();
} else if (item instanceof Product) {
    Product p = (Product)item;
    p.someProductMethod();
}
```

Comment: Or you could do `((Equipment)item).getEquipmentVin()`

Comment: You are 100% right. In essence my example is no different from the other answer - I just wanted to make it plain explicit rather than short.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cast to call a method from the `Equipment` class. Alternatively, you can use pattern matching for `instanceof`. Note, however, that this may likely be a symptom of improper design.

```java
if (i instanceof Equipment e) {
    e.getEquipmentVin();
} else if (i instanceof Product p) {
    p.someProductMethod();
}
```

Comment: A very good advice!